STM32f4 TIM5 Input Capture
I am encountering a problem with TIM5 CH3 CH4 when configured as *Input Capture direct mode

where stimulating TIM5_CH3 (PA2) writes data to the Capture and compare register (CCR4) and vice versa - stimulating TIM5_CH4 writes data to CCR3. Any ideas?

Timer initialization
static void MX_TIM5_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM5_Init 0 */
    __HAL_RCC_TIM5_CLK_ENABLE();
  /* USER CODE END TIM5_Init 0 */

  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};
  TIM_IC_InitTypeDef sConfigIC = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM5_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM5_Init 1 */
  htim5.Instance = TIM5;
  htim5.Init.Prescaler = 0;
  htim5.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim5.Init.Period = 4294967295;
  htim5.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim5.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_IC_Init(&htim5) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim5, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sConfigIC.ICPolarity = TIM_INPUTCHANNELPOLARITY_BOTHEDGE;
  sConfigIC.ICSelection = TIM_ICSELECTION_DIRECTTI;
  sConfigIC.ICPrescaler = TIM_ICPSC_DIV1;
  sConfigIC.ICFilter = 0;
  if (HAL_TIM_IC_ConfigChannel(&htim5, &sConfigIC, TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_TIM_IC_ConfigChannel(&htim5, &sConfigIC, TIM_CHANNEL_2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_TIM_IC_ConfigChannel(&htim5, &sConfigIC, TIM_CHANNEL_3) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_TIM_IC_ConfigChannel(&htim5, &sConfigIC, TIM_CHANNEL_4) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM5_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM5_Init 2 */

}

STM32F411RET6 LQFP64
Tried to configure input capture to load data into CCR3 and CCR4, expected TIM5_CH3 to write data to CCR3 and TIM5_CH4 to CCR4.
Same behaviour on TIM2. CH1 and CH2 write to CCR1 and CCR2 respectively.

The behaviour you are describing is expected if you use TIM_ICSELECTION_INDIRECTTI rather than TIM_ICSELECTION_DIRECTTI.
Double check the code and the GPIO configuration.  Check you have the correct pins connected to your signal!

Thanks for the answer! I see that TIM_ICSELECTION_INDIRECTTI would cause this behaviour, but I am not seeing the same pattern for CH1 and CH2.
